# af:inputFile is not calling valueChangeListener method

Tags: oracle-adf

**Summarize the problem**

I'm trying to upload an image to a blob in the database and have been following various blogs online to do so.

**Provide background including what you've already tried**

I've tried enclosing the input file on a form but I get the warning:-
"Only one af:form is supported per page. This warning later escalates to a server exception error and I can't enter said page.

**Show some code**

```
 <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
      <f:facet name="footer"/>
      <af:form id="f1" usesUpload="true">
        <af:inputFile label="Label 1" id="if1"  value="#NewUploadImageBean.file}"
                      valueChangeListener="#{NewUploadImageBean.upLoadValueChangeListener}"/>
      </af:form>
    </af:panelFormLayout>
```

I only have this one form in the entire page.

**Describe expected and actual results including any error messages**

Would like to the valueChangeListner to call my method. Currently I get the 
ADF_FACES-60097 error which then translates to : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ADF_FACES-30124:Multiple forms detected on viewId: /test_pages/employement.jsf. Rich client currently has some limitations in dealing with multiple forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADF af:inputFile does not trigger ValueChangeEvent with valueChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032476/adf-afinputfile-does-not-trigger-valuechangeevent-with-valuechangelistener)

Comment: Beaware not to have a form on a form. Just have only one form tag at the document level with useUpload="true" no need to add a <af:form right before the inputFile. Having one is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix **ADF_FACES-30124:Multiple forms detected on viewId** ?

To do so remove all the af:forms inside your jsf view expecially the one containing your inputFile and add only one af:form useupload="true" at the highest view tag level :

```
<af:document > 
 <af:form usesUpload="true" id="f1">
... ALL YOUR VIEW TAGS ...
</af:form>
</af:document>
```