# creating a popup (not form) to upload a file in ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I want to create a popup/dialog that has a *af:inputfile* component and save it in a server path using a managed bean. when I use a popup the file goes empty after clicking upload button

I did this using *form* but the problem is that page has already using another form so multiple forms error appeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [af:inputFile is not calling valueChangeListener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761903/afinputfile-is-not-calling-valuechangelistener-method)

Answer (score 0):

Web Page:

```
<af:popup id="p1" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" >
   <af:dialog id="d3" type="none" title=""
                     closeIconVisible="false">
            <f:facet name="buttonBar">
              <af:group id="g3">
                <af:commandButton text="Save" id="cb2" 
                                  partialSubmit="true"
                                  actionListener="#{myMB.onSaveAl}"/>
              </af:group>
            </f:facet>
            <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2">

              <af:inputFile  value="" id="if1" autoSubmit="true" required="true"
                            valueChangeListener="#{myMB.browseAndUpload}"  showRequired="true"/>
            </af:panelFormLayout>
 </af:dialog>
```

managed bean:

```
public void browseAndUpload(ValueChangeEvent event) 
{
    // The event give access to an Uploade dFile which contains data about the file and its content
    UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)event.getNewValue();
}
```

Comment: The file disappear immediately after uploading it (before clicking Save button) and throws
<oracle.adf.view><DimensionCandidate>..<illegal conflicting panelGridLayout....>because already found a different value for the same dimension in the grid geometry 14%

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag make the `usesUpload="true"`.

This will solve the problem.